# How to query 'transposed' table with complicated constraints

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
table1
id     name      value
-----------------------
 1       n1        v11
 1       n2        v12
 1       ...       ...
 1       nm        v1m
 2       n1        v21
 2       n2        v22
 2       ...       ...
 2       nm        v2m
 ...
 ...
 k       n1        vk1
 k       n2        vk2
 k       ...       ...
 k       nm        vkm
```

In this table, each id must have the same set of names, although we do not know what they are w/o reading the table.

And I wanted to get all the ids with the following constraints

1) if name = ni, then value = 42
2) if name = nj, then value = 24

If the above table is written as the following, then we can do

```
 select id from table2 where ni = 42 and nj = 24

 table2
 id    n1    n2   ...   nm
 ---------------------------
  1    v11   v12  ...   v1m
  2    v21   v22  ...   v2m
  ...
  k    vk1   vk2  ...   vkm
```

But in the original table1, I am not sure what is the best way to do so.
Maybe for this constraint, there can be an adhoc query. However, if the constraint is more complicated, like
    n1 != 19 or not (n2 = 55 and n3 = 44) 
I cannot find a general solution.

I could make table1 defined as table2. But to add a new name to table2, we have to change the design of table2 by adding a new column... Is there any better solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `table2` because it can be generated from `table1` using a pivot query:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'n1' THEN value END) AS n1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'n2' THEN value END) AS n2,
       ...
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'nm' THEN value END) AS nm
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Biegeieisen: Interesting use of group by and max! Also 'query plan' shows that this query is also efficient. Thank you.

Comment: @JoeC If you need to change the values, just do so in `table1` and then pivot out `table2` using my query.